# How to create a list of subdirectories in a list of directories in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

First of all, I'm not allowed to use more for or while loops because this is task for university.

I have the following:

```
for i in {00..20}
do  
    users=( $(ls "$dir"/"$1" | grep "room_${i}_*" | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '_' -f 3-4 | sort | uniq) )
    cd "$dir"/"$2"/r"${i}" || exit
    mkdir -p "${users[@]}"/{MP4,MOV,AVI,WMV,MKV}
done
```

I have bunch of videos named room_XX_user_Y.ext, where XX is a number between 00 and 20, Y is unknown and ext is one of {MP4,MOV,AVI,WMV,MKV}. So, I have to move the file to /rXX/user_Y/ext/ and I have to create all of them except rXX (r stands for room). Every user has a video with this extensions.

I'm able to do everything except creating all the {MP4,MOV,AVI,WMV,MKV} directories inside the user_Y directory. If the users for a room are a, b, c and d, the directories for extensions will only be created on the user_d directory.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

srcdir=$1
destdir=$2

shopt -s extglob nullglob
for video_path in "$srcdir"/room_[0-9][0-9]_user_*.@(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV); do
    room_xx_user_y_ext=${video_path##*/}
    ext=${room_xx_user_y_ext##*.}
    room_xx_user_y=${room_xx_user_y_ext%.*}
    xx_user_y=${room_xx_user_y#room_}
    xx=${xx_user_y%%_*}
    user_y=${xx_user_y#*_}

    video_destdir="$destdir/r${xx}/${user_y}/${ext}"
    mkdir -pv -- "$video_destdir"
    mv -iv -- "$video_path" "$video_destdir"
done
```

- The `extglob` argument to `shopt -s` enables extended globs in Bash, to support the `@(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV)` pattern.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
- The `nullglob` argument to `shopt -s` causes glob patterns that don't match anything to expand to nothing (instead of (what amounts to) garbage), making them safe to loop over.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for explanations of the string manipulations used to extract the parts of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting the following solution:

#### 1. Locate all the files with `find` command.

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex "^room_([01][0-9]|20)_user_[^\.]+\.(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV)$"
```

Improve this command till you locate all designated files. And only required files ( `room_21_user_x.MP4 room_20_user_x..MP4 room_20_user_x.Mp4 room_20_user_x.MP Room_20_user_x.MP4 room_20_user_x.MP43` etc...)

#### 2. Dissect each file name to its compoents

```
for currFile in $(find . -regextype egrep -regex "^room_([01][0-9]|20)_user_[^\.]+\.(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV)$"); do 
   currFileName=$(basename $currFile)
   xx=${currFileName:5:2}
   y=${currFileName:13}
   y=${y::-4}
   ext=${currFileName:(-3):3}
   printf "xx=%s y=%s ext=%s\n" $xx $y $ext
done
```

Improve the string dissection to perfection.

#### 3. Rebuild destination path

```
for currFile in $(find . -regextype egrep -regex "^room_([01][0-9]|20)_user_[[:alpha:]]\.(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV)$"); do 
   currFileName=$(basename $currFile)
   xx=${currFileName:5:2}
   y=${currFileName:13}
   y=${y::-4}
   ext=${currFileName:(-3):3}
   destinationPath="/r${xx}/user_${y}/${ext}}"
   echo "destinationPath=$destinationPath"       
done
```

Make sure destination path is correct for each file.

#### 4. Build the destination file, and relocate the file there

```
for currFile in $(find . -regextype egrep -regex "^room_([01][0-9]|20)_user_[[:alpha:]]\.(MP4|MOV|AVI|WMV|MKV)$"); do 
   currFileName=$(basename $currFile)
   xx=${currFileName:5:2}
   y=${currFileName:13}
   y=${y::-4}
   ext=${currFileName:(-3):3}
   destinationPath="/r${xx}/user_${y}/${ext}}"
   mkdir -p "$destinationPath"    
   mv currFile "$destinationPath" 
done

Do be bothered with the creation of `/r${xx}`.
```

Because `mkdir -p` creates only directories missing in the argument path. `mkdir -p` ignore existing paths as stated [here](https://manpage.me/?q=mkdir). Therefore it is safe to use `mkdir -p` again on existing paths.

If you care to check that `/r${xx}` is writable directory before assigning it to `mkdir -p`

```
if [[ -d "/r${xx}" && -w "/r${xx}" ]]; then
   mkdir -p "$destinationPath"    
   mv currFile "$destinationPath" 
fi
```